# How do i redirect to an external site with phonegap inside the app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, redirect, browser

I have a single page in my phonegap app , that i want to redirect to an external page after some seconds , but it keeps redirecting outisude the app.But i want it to open in the app
Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the Codova API
setTimeout( window.location="http://www.autojosh.com" , '7000') ; }
     </script>
```

I have tried almost everything i know its not working please help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open the link inside your app, first of all, you need to install [InAppBrowser plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

when you have the plugin, the following code will open the page in a new window inside the app.

```
window.open('http://your-page.com', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes,toolbar=no');
```

Comment: Thanks bro , I would try that out , i used phonegap build an i added <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0"/> in my config.xml , is my timing code correct ?

Comment: yeah, I think that it looks ok :)

Comment: Still the same bro ,its still asking to open in an external browser,please help me

Comment: you need to be sure that the plugin is installed correctly. You can type in the console `cordova.InAppBrowser` and you have to receive an object, not `undefined`.

Comment: The plugin is properly installed bro , I am confused myself , have any other clues ?

Comment: Or is it possible that the timeout is conflicting ? , what other way can i redirect after some seconds ?

Comment: You need to fix your setTimeout() function. It has to be: `setTimeout(function(){ window.open('http://your-page.com', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes,toolbar=no'); }, 3000);`

Answer (score 1):

Not for OP since this is so old, but for anyone looking for the same, the way to enable navigation to external URLs inside the main webview is by adding the following to the `config.xml` file:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

Set `https` or `http` accordingly.

Unlike with the InAppBrowser, this way the page can access the Cordova API, if you upload and include the JS files for the platform you're using.